# How to reset a menu to initial state in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a multi-state menu UI component.

This is what I want to happen:

1) click on Avatar button/link
2) choose an option from the menu
3) choose option "Take Pic with Camera" and menu should expand to the right
4) when I click away the menu goes away and it collapses again
5) when I click the avatar to close the menu and then open it back up it's still in expanded mode; but I want it collapsed again.

That's what I mean by resetting the menu to initial state in the title.

Here's a codepen http://codepen.io/MARS/pen/MYGRdo (note it looks totally busted on the codepen obviously it's missing images but you can still see the functionality. (all code below)

Also here is a 59 second screencast showing the desired result:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j2qtNv1Osig

HTML:

```
<div class="child-profile-wrapper">


    <div class="child-profile-container">

        <div id="photoMenuCont" class="add-photo-container">
            <div id="photoMenu" class="photo-menu photo-menu-collapsed">
                <div class="photo-menu-left-col">
                    <h4>Add Photo</h4>
                    <span class="photo-menu-divider"></span>
                    <ul class="photo-menu-fields">
                        <li><a id="noPhoto" href="#"><span class="menu-initials">BR</span>Initials (no photo)</a></li>
                        <span class="photo-menu-divider"></span>
                        <li><a id="takePhoto" href="#"><span class="menu-camera"></span>Take photo with camera</a></li>
                        <span class="photo-menu-divider"></span>
                        <li><a id="uploadPhoto" href="#"><span class="menu-upload"></span>Upload a picture</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="photo-menu-right-col">
                    <h6>Please press the button to access your camera</h6>
                    <a id="cameraTrigger" class="user-camera-button" href="#"><span class="menu-camera-icon"></span><span class="camera-button-text">Use my camera!</span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <span class="arrow-left"></span>
        </div>

        <div id="leftCol" class="child-profile-left-col">
            <div id="initialAvatar" class="avatar-container">
                <a id="avatarTrigger" href="#" class="avatar boy"><span class="avatar-photo-link">+Add Photo</span><span class="avatar-update-link"></span></span></a>
            </div>

            <div class="child-profile-row">
                <ul class="child-profile-fields half print-font">
                    <li>
                        <span class="child-profile-label">Enrollment Status</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Active</a>
                    </li>

                     <li>
                        <span class="child-profile-label">Start Date</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span class="child-profile-content">Aug 20, 2012</span>
                    </li>

                     <li>
                        <span class="child-profile-label">Grade</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span class="child-profile-content">Pre-Kinder</span>
                    </li>

                     <li>
                        <span class="child-profile-label">School</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span class="child-profile-content">Fair Lakes Children Center</span>
                    </li>

                     <li>
                        <span class="child-profile-label">Photos Authorized?</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span>TOGGLE</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div id="rightCol" class="child-profile-right-col">
            <div class="child-profile-row border">
                <ul class="child-profile-fields thirds lrg-font">
                    <li>
                        <span class="child-profile-label">First Name</span>
                        <span class="child-profile-content">Bam Bam</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span class="child-profile-label">Middle Name</span>
                        <span class="child-profile-content">Crush</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span class="child-profile-label">Last Name</span>
                        <span class="child-profile-content">Rubble</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="child-profile-row border">
                <ul class="child-profile-fields thirds md-font">
                    <li>
                        <span class="child-profile-label">D.O.B</span>
                        <span class="child-profile-content">April 23, 2012</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span class="child-profile-label">Sex</span>
                        <span class="child-profile-content">Male</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span class="child-profile-label">Nickname</span>
                        <span class="child-profile-content">Flint</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="child-profile-row border">
                <ul class="child-profile-fields thirds sml-font">
                    <li>
                        <span class="child-profile-label">Identity Document Number</span>
                        <span class="child-profile-content">AW-1235465878</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span class="child-profile-label">Identity Document Type</span>
                        <span class="child-profile-content">U.S. Passport</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span class="child-profile-label">Document Date Issued</span>
                        <span class="child-profile-content">May 5, 2013</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="child-profile-row">
                <div class="child-profile-notes-row">
                    <span class="child-profile-label">Notes</span>
                    <a href="#" class="btn-launch-skypad">Launch SkyPad</a>
                </div>
                <ul class="child-profile-fields full print-font">
                    <li>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ornare, est eget fringilla auctor, diam ante ultrices turpis, ac congue sapien eros a turpis. Morbi quis pellentesque purus. Proin suscipit, ipsum et ornare euismod, est risus imperdiet augue, sit amet semper dolor velit in metus. In tempor, arcu vitae eleifend gravida, sapien dolor ultrices nisl.</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="notes-container">
                    <li><a href="#" class="notes-item">
                        <h3>Subject Line</h3>
                        <span class="notes-divider"></span>
                        <span class="notes-date">Wednesday Feb 18, 2015</span>
                    </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="notes-item">
                        <h3>Subject Line</h3>
                        <span class="notes-divider"></span>
                        <span class="notes-date">Wednesday Feb 18, 2015</span>
                    </a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="child-profile-bottom-border"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var photoMenuCont = $('#photoMenuCont'),
    menu = $('#photoMenu'),
    noPhoto = $('#noPhoto'),
    takePhoto = $('#takePhoto'),
    uploadPhoto = $('#uploadPhoto'),
    cameraTrigger = $('#cameraTrigger'),
    rightCol = $("#rightCol"),
    leftCol = $('#leftCol'),
    avatarTrigger = $('#avatarTrigger');

    takePhoto.on('click', function(){
      menu.toggleClass('photo-menu-collapsed photo-menu-expanded');
    });

    avatarTrigger.on('click', function(){
      photoMenuCont.fadeToggle('700' , 'linear');
      if($(document).hasClass('.photo-menu-expanded')) {
        removeClass('photo-menu-expanded');
      }
      return false;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this alternative `avatarTrigger` block.
You should call `.hasClass('something')` instead of `.hasClass('.something')`.
And you need to reset both the expanded and collapsed classes instead of just one.

```
avatarTrigger.on('click', function(){
      photoMenuCont.fadeToggle('700' , 'linear');
      if(menu.hasClass('photo-menu-expanded')) {
            menu.toggleClass('photo-menu-collapsed photo-menu-expanded');
      }
      return false;
});
```

Comment: you are nothing short of AWESOME! Thank you worked perfectly and the approach was a simple modification. Excellent!